# Problem with importing module rospy in python（win10）

Tags: python, ros, pybullet

I have installed ROS on win10(http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows), and the turtle can also move by pressing the arrow keys. I also installed pybullet through Anaconda3 and used python to import some modules such as

```
import pybullet as p 
import pybullet_data as pd
import numpy as np
import time
```

There is no problem in use. But importing rospy

```
import rospy
```

does not work, and it prompts "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'rospy'". why is that? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [rospy](https://pypi.org/project/roslibpy/) package by

```
pip install roslibpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Consindering you are using anaconda, open anaconda prompt and then enter the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ros-rospy
```

to install the rospy library

Comment: What is not working about it? What is your error? It is still saying it is not installed?

Comment: There is no problem with the installation according to your method. However, import rospy still reports an error.